# Why list become empty outside the method in Angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular js and I have a get method  **'$scope.getAllEmployeesList'**. In this method I put the response data into the '$scope.employeeList'. However, list contains data only inside the method but it become empty outside the get method.

Here is my code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('basicInfoController', function ($scope, $http, $location) {

$scope.submitForm = function () {

    var url = "http://localhost:8080/basicInfo/save";
    var data = {
        employeeId: $scope.employeeId,
        firstName: $scope.firstName,
        lastName: $scope.lastName,
        companyId: $scope.companyId,
        phoneNo: $scope.phoneNo,
        sexId: $scope.sexId,
        sexName: $scope.sexName,
        birthDate: $scope.birthDate,
        joiningDate: $scope.joiningDate,
        department: $scope.department
    };
    $http.post(url, data).then(function (response) {
        $scope.postResultMessage = "Sucessful!";
        $scope.successMessage = 'User created successfully';
    }, function (response) {
        $scope.postResultMessage = "Fail!";
    });
            $scope.employeeId = "";
            $scope.firstName = "";
            $scope.lastName = "";
            $scope.companyId = "";
            $scope.phoneNo = "";
            $scope.sexId = "";
            $scope.sexName = "";
            $scope.birthDate = "";
            $scope.joiningDate = "";
            $scope.department = "";
    }

    $scope.employeeList =[];
    $scope.getAllEmployeesList = function () {

        var url = $location.absUrl() + "basicInfo/getAllEmployeeBasicInfo";

        var config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8;'
            }
        }
        $http.get(url, config).then(function (response) {
            $scope.employeeList = response.data;
            $scope.employeeList = angular.copy(response.data);
            console.log($scope.employeeList);
        }, function (response) {
            $scope.getResultMessage = "Fail!";

        });
    }

    $scope.getAllEmployeesList();
    console.log($scope.employeeList);

    function reset() {

        $scope.basicInfo = {
            employeeId: '',
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            phoneNo: '',
            sex: '',
            birthDate: '',
            companyId: '',
            department: '',
            joiningDate: ''

        };

        $scope.myForm.$setPristine(); //reset Form
    }
});
```

**in $scope.getAllEmployeesList method, when I print 'console.log($scope.employeeList);'  inside the method then it is showing value but if print out side the method then empty list is shown.**

Comment: It's likely because $scope.getAllEmployeesList is the async call function, the outer layer console.log is run before the function get executed and finished. That explain why the inner console.log got the value while the outer console.log is empty.

Comment: How do I solve this problem now?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code, you just need to wait the asynchronous function ($scope.getAllEmployeesList) to executed and finished. Eventually the $scope.employeeList will have the value.

Answer (score 0):

Just return the $http... then tack on another .then().

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])
.controller('basicInfoController', function ($scope, $http, $location) {

    function submitForm() {
        var url = "http://localhost:8080/basicInfo/save";
        var data = {
            employeeId: $scope.employeeId,
            firstName: $scope.firstName,
            lastName: $scope.lastName,
            companyId: $scope.companyId,
            phoneNo: $scope.phoneNo,
            sexId: $scope.sexId,
            sexName: $scope.sexName,
            birthDate: $scope.birthDate,
            joiningDate: $scope.joiningDate,
            department: $scope.department
        };

        $http.post(url, data).then(function() {
            $scope.postResultMessage = "Sucessful!";
            $scope.successMessage = 'User created successfully';
        }, function() {
            $scope.postResultMessage = "Fail!";
        });

        $scope.employeeId = "";
        $scope.firstName = "";
        $scope.lastName = "";
        $scope.companyId = "";
        $scope.phoneNo = "";
        $scope.sexId = "";
        $scope.sexName = "";
        $scope.birthDate = "";
        $scope.joiningDate = "";
        $scope.department = "";
    }

    $scope.employeeList = [];

    function getAllEmployeesList() {
        var url = $location.absUrl() + "basicInfo/getAllEmployeeBasicInfo";

        var config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8;'
            }
        }

        return $http.get(url, config).then(function() {
            $scope.employeeList = response.data;
            $scope.employeeList = angular.copy(response.data);
        }, function() {
            $scope.getResultMessage = "Fail!";
        });
    }

    getAllEmployeesList().then(function() {
        console.log($scope.employeeList);
    });

    function reset() {

        $scope.basicInfo = {
            employeeId: '',
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            phoneNo: '',
            sex: '',
            birthDate: '',
            companyId: '',
            department: '',
            joiningDate: ''

        };

        $scope.myForm.$setPristine(); //reset Form
    }

    $scope.getAllEmployeesList = getAllEmployeesList;
    $scope.submitForm = submitForm;
});
```